# Pytorch Convolutional Layer returning Nan

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network, pytorch

so I am using a convolutional layer as the first layer of a neural network for deep reinforcement learning to get the spatial features out of a simulation I built. The simulation gives different maps that are of different lengths and heights to process. If I understand convolutional networks, this should not matter since the channel size is kept constant. In between the convolutional network and the fully connected layers there is a spatial pyramid pooling layer so that the varying image sizes does not matter. Also the spatial data is pretty sparse. Usually it is able to go through a few states and sometimes a few episodes before the first convolutional layer spits out all Nans. Even when I fix the map size this happens. I do not know where the problem lies, where can the problem lie?

Comment: The title is a little bit misleading, but chances are your values simply diverge due to a large learning rate, bad regularization of parameters (are you using Batch Normalization?)

Also, can you share more details about your implementation? Maybe some code? What hyperparameters are you currently using? What opitmizer? You have to give a little more detail if you expect help on such a topic.

Comment: I am using batch normalization, but this happens at the first layer before a leaky ReLU or batch normalization can be applied. I am using a cyclical learning that has been range tested using the SGD+Momentum optimizer.

Comment: It does not matter where it happens, the problem is that your backpropagation step might increase/decrease your weights of the layer to such an extent that the network will compute NaNs in the next forward pass. Please share your code if you expect reasonable answers, otherwise it is really hard to tell what is wrong. And name your parameters, like learning rate, learning rate decay, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize your weights with random numbers between 0 and 1 and then try different learning rates for your network training. (I suggest test it with learning rates equal to 10, 1, 0.1, 0.01, ...)